# Trigonometry sum of solutions question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> *Problem:* For which $a$ will the sum of solutions be equal to $100$, in $\sin(\sqrt{ax-x^2})=0$.

*The attempt at a solution:*
For $\sin(x)=0$, $x$ must be equal to $0$, so we get $$\sqrt{ax-x^2}=0\\ax-x^2=0\\x(a-x)=0\\x=0\\a-x=0$$last 2 are the solutions as I understand but I can't seem to finalize the solution, please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, the sum of solutions $$x+a-x$$

Comment: So, $a$ must be equal to $100$ right? in order for sum of solution to be 100.

Comment: In that case, $$ax-x^2=(k\pi)^2\implies x^2-ax+(k\pi)^2=0\implies x_1+x_2=a$$ considering a specific $k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct so far, to answer the question, all you need to do is set sum of the solutions equal to $100$, $$x+a-x=100\\a=100$$ so a must be equal to $100$ in order for sum of solutions to be $100$.

Comment: These are not all the solutions of the equation...

Comment: (comment retracted)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no such $a$. Note that

$$\sin(\sqrt{ax-x^2}) = 0 \iff \sqrt{ax-x^2}=k \pi$$

for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Squaring both sides of the second equation and solving the second degree equation shows

$$x_{1,k} = \frac{a}{2} +\frac{\sqrt{a^2-4k^2\pi^2}}{2} \text{ and }x_{2,k} = \frac{a}{2} -\frac{\sqrt{a^2-4k^2\pi^2}}{2}$$

In particular we have $x_{1,k}+x_{2,k} = a$. These solutions exists as long as 
$$a^2 - 4\pi^2k^2 \geq 0 \iff \frac{|a|}{2\pi} \geq |k|.$$
In particular if $N$ denotes the integer part of $\frac{|a|}{2\pi}$, then the sum of all solutions is give by $S=a2N$. Asking for $S=100$ leads to the equation
$$a(2\lfloor |a|/2\pi\rfloor+1) = 100,$$
where $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ denotes the floor function. [It follows that](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282+a%29*floor%28%7Ca%7C%2F%282%5Cpi%29%29%2Ba+%3D+100+solve+for+a+real) there is no solution.

Comment: Are you sure of this result ?

Comment: @Surb What of the case when k is negative? Wouldn't that involve the ceiling function instead of the floor function?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici There may still be typos but I think this a valid way to solve this problem. And I'm also completely sure that the solution $\sin(\sqrt{100x-x^2})=0$ has more than two solutions.

Comment: @Deepak the strictly negative $k$ are represented by the factor $2$ and $k=0$ by the $+1$ in $2\lfloor |a|/2\pi\rfloor+1$.

Comment: @Surb I have to think about this (doing something else at the time). I'm not certain (yet) your answer is completely correct, but I'm leaving the upvote because this is certainly the right *way* to think about the problem, at the very least. The other "best answer" is totally wrong.

Comment: @Surb. You last input to WA shows no real solution. But I totally agree with you on the fact that this is more than one solution. Cheers :)

Comment: @Deepak I understand your "prudence" (and thank you for leaving the upvote) and would be interested to know where is the mistake if there is one.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Unfortunately I have to admit that I don't really know how to solve this equation involving the floor function... If you have an idea, it's very welcome :).

Comment: @Surb. May I confess that I do not know either ? Welcome to the club ! Cheers :)